# Concatenate dataframe rows and match when key is the same

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframe, df1 and df2 and I am trying to figure out a way to generate df3 as you see in the screenshot:
[image]

So, the goal here is to retain all the rows of df1 and append rows of df2 under them. However, I want to have one single row for matching Name, Lat and Lon. So, Name, Lat and Lon will be used as a keys.

There's also the issue of the ZIP column. I want to retain the ZIP value of df1 when for rows that are joined.

I tried:

```
df3=pandas.merge(df1,df2,on=['Name','Lat','Lon'],how='outer')
```

That produced something close to what I want:

[image]

As you see the above dataframe came up with two different ZIP and Address columns.

Any idea on how to get the clean df3 dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think 'merge' is appropriate for this task (ie, joining left DF on right DF), since you are really putting one DF on top of another and then dropping the duplicates. So you could try someting like:

```
#put one DF 'on top' of the other (like-named columns should drop into place)
df3 = pandas.concat([df1, df2])
#get rid of any duplicates
df3.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
```

**EDIT**

With your feedback I realize a bit dirtier solution is needed. You would use a merge and then fill the NaN's from the duplicate columns. Something like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'test':[1,2,3,6,np.nan, np.nan]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'test':[np.nan,np.nan,3,6,10,24]})

#some merge statement to get them into together into the var 'df'
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index = True, right_index=True)

#collect the _x columns
original_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.endswith('_x')]

for col in original_cols:
    #use the duplicate column to fill the NaN's of the original column
    duplicate = col.replace('_x', '_y')
    df[col].fillna(df[duplicate], inplace = True)

    #drop the duplicate
    df.drop(duplicate, axis = 1, inplace = True)

    #rename the original to remove the '_x'
    df.rename(columns = {col:col.replace('_x', '')}, inplace = True)
```

let me know if this works.

Comment: Sorry, I had to unaccept your answer. I realize this is not what I was looking for. For instance, Clocks need to get both the value of the Reviews and the Public column from the two dataframes. So, there should be a merge operations involved.